# Using <input type="file"> to display uploaded files with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input-type-file

I want to use a file input so that a user could upload a folder containing their site files, then the program finds the index file in the folder then displays it in the iframe.

I attepted to do this myself (shown below) using a folder containing a simple html and css file, but index.html would never load.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="fileSelect" webkitdirectory>

        <iframe id="iframeView" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
        
        <script>
            //Instantiate to reduce visual complexity
            const frameElement = document.getElementById("iframeView");
            const fileElement = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
            
            //Call loadURL when a folder is selected
            fileElement.addEventListener("change", loadURL);
            
            //Get index.html file from folder and make it the iframe src
            function loadURL() {
                frameElement.src = fileElement.files["index.html"];
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the `index.html` file in the selected folder. And use The [`FileReader API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader) to read its content.

```js
const frameElement = document.getElementById("iframeView");
const fileElement = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
fileElement.addEventListener("change", loadURL);

function loadURL() {
  const files = Array.from(fileElement.files);
  const indexFile = files.find((file) => file.name === "index.html");
  if (indexFile) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      frameElement.src = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(indexFile);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileSelect" webkitdirectory />
<iframe id="iframeView" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. I would upvote 100% if I was able to.
Edit: Literally just got the ability to upvote, thanks again

Comment: You don't need the FileReader... just do: `frameElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(indexFile)`

Comment: @Endless If you know it, just fix it! we are here to help each other not to downvote answers we have put some effort to answer them!

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `readAsDataURL` all worked fine for small files, but when the size increased, we started to see issues.

Issues:

1. The `URL max length` is different across multiple browsers, so this would be one big restriction in some browsers the URL max length and in some not but not showing it.
2. The `readAsDataURL` converts the buffer to a base64 string and keeps it in memory. When you are not using it, the memory gets cleared up by the garbage collector.

As a solution for all these issues, I used the `readAsArrayBuffer` and created an object URL.

```
function createfileURL(file){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            const buffer = e.target.result;
            const fileBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)], { type: file.type})
            return resolve(window.URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob));
        };
    })
}
```

Comment: What a wasteful use of the `FileReader`... file are instances of blobs so you don't need to construct a own in-memory blob... instead do: `URL.createObjectURL(file)` directly instead

Comment: this is actually what I was looking for because of the large files caveat. it's performance is significantly better when immediately showing a preview of the large selected file